# Dependent observables for subsequent api calls

Tags: android, rx-java, reactive-programming

I'm going to try and keep this as simple as possible.
I have two API endpoints, `httpA` and `httpB` that return observables:

- When I hit endpoint `httpA` it returns a stream of objects `A`.
- Likewise, when I hit endpoint `httpB` it will return a stream of objects `B`

This is all well and simple. I need to zip the responses together like this:

```
httpA().zipWith(httpB(), new Func2<A, B, SomeCombinationAB> {
   public SomeCombinationAB call(A a, B b) {
      return new SomeCombinationAB(a,b);
   }
});
```

The problem is, `HttpB` takes as a parameter all of `Objects A`.

HttpB(List A)

So, I need to somehow gather **All** `Objects A` before being able to trigger `HttpB`. That is, block the stream until all A have been delivered.
I think I can do this using `toList()` operator.

Once I have the list of `As`, I have to convert back to a stream of `A` to be able to zip both streams:

```
    List<A> aList;

    httpA.toList().flatMap(new Func1<List<A>, Observable<A>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<A> call(List<A> listA) {
            aList = listA;
            return Observable.from(listA);
        }
    }).zipWith(httpB(aList), new Func2<A, B, SomeCombinationAB> {
        public SomeCombinationAB call (A a, B b){
            return new SomeCombinationAB(a, b);
        }
    });
```

This is working, but it certainly doesn't feel right. I'm converting a stream back and forth. I'm not sure how the toList() operator behaves if the stream of A is very very long.
I'm sure there's a better way to solve this.

Any help is appreciated
Thanks

**Update 1**

To put this in context, I'm trying to implement a chat-like application.
 The object `A` in my example are `Conversations`, and the object `B` are `User Profile`s (user information).

When trying to fetch the list of recent conversations for the logged in user:

1. I bring my `Conversations` from the server first (`httpA`), these have an user id but not the actual `User Info` name/details.
2. To get the `User Info` I have to hit the server again passing in all of the user ids I'm interested in (this is `httpB` in the example above).

So "very very long" could be 0, 100, 300 conversations. I don't think this is going to be a problem because `toList()` is a blocking operator. But I'm pretty new to Rx, so I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "very very long"? It sounds like you might need to handle back-pressure in some way. Also, how flexible is `httpB`? Could you sample the results of httpA and provide lossy data to httpB?  If you absolutely need all the data from it, then I'm not sure what alternative you have to your second snippet.

Comment: Thanks, please see my updated question. My current snippet is working just fine :) if there are no better alternatives I have no problem sticking to it.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO a better approach here would be to move the logic you have now in zip operator to the point where you emit `B` events as you have the appropriate information within the method already and combine the related results in there...

You will lose the the flatMap operator and reverting listA back to a stream .. I didn't benchmarked it, but I would say that the performance overhead won't be that much noticeable with 100's of items.. Moreover, I don't know how your `httpB()` methods looks like so it might just get your code worse in there just for the sake of stream readability ..

Answer (score 0):

well I came up with the same solution. For testing I use RxJava2-RC5.

```
@Test
public void flatMap21() throws Exception {
        Observable<String> stringObservable = endpointA()
                .toList()
                .flatMapObservable(strings -> endpointB(strings)
                        .zipWith(strings, (integer, s) -> {
                            return "combined";
                        })
                );

        TestObserver<String> test = stringObservable.test();

        test.assertValueCount(3);
}

private Observable<String> endpointA() {
        return Observable.just("1", "2", "3");
}

private Observable<Integer> endpointB(List<String> input) {
        return Observable.just(1, 2, 3);
}
```

One possible solution is batching the work into chunks if web-calls are cheap.

The observable would look something like this, if you were to use batch-size 5.

```
Observable<String> stringObservable = endpointA()
                .buffer(5)
                .flatMap(strings -> endpointB(strings)
                        .zipWith(strings, (integer, s) -> {
                            return "combined";
                        }));
```